# Is it possible to move a destiny character from one profile to another?

Tags: xbox-network, destiny

I can't use my hunter on my profile anymore. is it possible to make a new Xbox live profile but still keep my character?

Comment: This sentence: `I can't use my hunter on my profile anymore` makes me quite curious as to why. Is this due to a ban (*out of our scope*)? Is this due to a cost of membership (*call microsoft*)? Is the save corrupted(*file a support ticket with bungie*)? Was it on a different Xbox altogether (*Microsoft has a transfer utility designed for this, but also Destiny is an MMORPG, thus profiles transfer!*)?

Comment: I just lost access to the account.

Comment: Call Microsoft then, unless it was a friend's account. You can regain access so long as you were the true owner of the account.

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no way to transfer a character from one profile to another.

Comment: In order to elaborate on this, You cannot transfer characters due to the fact that characters are stored on a Bungie server.

Comment: @ColeBusby there are a number of reasons. Actually, being stored on Bungie's server would mean it would be more likely, as Bungie would call the shots on which profile a character is stored on. They just chose not to.

Comment: What I meant was that the backhanded method of changing the save ID through something like Modio (** This violates a Microsoft Terms of Service **) is out of the question. Of course if Bungie allowed that, then different story altogether, however some games (Assassin's Creed 1) could have their save data altered so that any player with the application can launch the save and obtain the achievements/trophies etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to transfer any of you Destiny characters to a new Xbox Live profile. Bungie saves all of our characters on there server and has them linked to the account that we made them on.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian.